# renaming file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a script which prepends zeros in the file name if the file name is less that 18 digits.

For example if the file name is `1234567`, then it should rename it to `000000000001234567` and if it is `123456789`, then it makes it `000000000123456789`. My code is already doing this functionality

Now my requirement is that if the file name is `1234567-1`, then it should make it `000000000001234567_Type_1` and if name is `1234567-a`, then it should rename it to `000000000001234567_Type_a`.

This means it should keep doing what my script doing but in addition it should suffix `_Type_<last character>` in the file name. File name can be `1234567` or `123456789` or `1234567-1` or `12345678-b` or any thing else but there are always digits and not characters before hyphen (-). There can be multiple files in a folder. Hyphens (-) should be replaced with underscores (_) followed by `Type_` and whatever is the last character in the file name.

Here is my existing code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem iterate over tif files:
 for %%f in (C:\Task\Drop_Files\*.tif) do (
    rem store file name without extension
    set FileName=%%~nf

    rem Add leading zeroes:
    set FileName=00000000000000000!FileName!

    set FileName=!FileName:~-18!

    set FileName=!FileName!%%~xf

    rem Rename the file
    rename "%%f" "!FileName!"

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should handle files with the hyphen suffix (like `1234567-1`) and without (like `1234567`) as you want:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem Iterate over TIF files:
for %%f in ("%~dp0*.tif") do (
    rem Store file name without extension:
    set "FileName=%%~nf"

    rem Split off hyphen and suffix:
    set "Suffix=!FileName:*-=!"
    if "!Suffix!"=="!FileName!" set "Suffix="
    call set "FileName=%%FileName:-!Suffix!=%%"
    if defined Suffix set "Suffix=_Type_!Suffix!"

    rem Add leading zeroes:
    set "FileName=00000000000000000!FileName!"

    rem Build final file name:
    set "FileName=!FileName:~-18!!Suffix!"

    rem Rename the file:
    rename "%%~ff" "!FileName!%%~xf"
)
```

What I did:

- introduced a new variable `Suffix` that will hold the character after the hyphen (for instance `1` when the file name is `1234567-1`); the suffix including the hyphen (like `-1`) will be removed from the file name (this would fail in case `-1` occurred more than once in the file name though);
- improved `set` syntax by adding quotes around the assignment expression;

Comment: If the original file name is 0000000000012783_1 then Your code is producing the file name as 0000000000012783_1_Type_0000000012783_1. It should be 0000000000012783_Type_1. Can you please advise what to do?

Comment: Sorry, I failed to apply delayed expansion for `Suffix` once -- see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39150386/2)...

Comment: Sorry, I had not tested the code extensively last week. It is working for some scenarios but not for one in particular. when the file name does not have any hyphen(-), then it does not work. For example, file name is 000075431. The script is converting it into 000000000000075431_Type_000075431. I want it to be 000000000000075431. Since there is no hyphen followed by any character so it should just make it 18 digits long. Can you please help?

Comment: Oops, I missed that when reading your question obviously; see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39150386/4) which fixes that...

Comment: is not doing anything now. Nothing happens

Comment: Now it is doing everything else but not assigning leading zeros to make it 18 digits. If this can't be done in one script then I can have a separate script to have leading zeros. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. In your original code, just before the "Rename" line, just add the following line:

```
set FileName=!FileName:-=_Type_!
```

That's it!

Comment: This would lead to a numeric part with 16 digits only for files suffixed with the hyphen part...

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks for your feedback but can you give me an example filename for which my solution wouldn't work?

Comment: For example: `1234567-1`; the result would be `0000000001234567_Type_1` (16 digits only before `_Type_` although there should be 18)...

Answer (score 0):

I think the following, slightly modified code, should do what you're looking for. Basically, you need to test whether the next to last character is a dash (-), in which case you replace it with **_Type_**.
To do that, you extract the last 2 characters of the FileName (without extension) then look at the first character of those two extracted chars. If it's a dash, then you eliminate the last two characters from the original filename because they will eventually be replaced with the new _Type_[char] construct.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem iterate over tif files:
 for %%f in (C:\tests\output*.txt) do (
    rem store file name without extension
    set FileName=%%~nf
    set IsDash=!FileName:~-2!
    set IsDash=!IsDash:~0,1!
    IF "!IsDash!" == "-" (
      SET FileType=_Type_!FileName:~-1!
      SET FileName=!FileName:~0,-2!
    ) ELSE (
       SET FileType=
    )

    rem Add leading zeroes:
    set FileName=00000000000000000!FileName!

    set FileName=!FileName:~-18!!FileType!

    set FileName=!FileName!%%~xf
    rem Rename the file
    rename "%%f" "!FileName!"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem Change current directory
cd /D C:\Task\Drop_Files

rem Iterate over tif files:
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-." %%f in ('dir /B *.tif') do (

    rem Store file name without extension and leading zeroes:
    set "FileName=00000000000000000%%f"

    rem Get the right type and input name:
    rem - If input name is "1234567.tif" then "%%h" is empty, so there is no Type part
    rem - If input name is "1234567-1.tif" then "%%h" is "tif", so the Type is "_Type_%%g"
    if "%%h" equ "" (
        set "input=%%f.%%g"
        set "type="
    ) else (
        set "input=%%f-%%g.%%h"
        set "type=_Type_%%g"
    )

    rem Rename the file
    rename "!input!" "!FileName:~-18!!type!.tif"

)
```